# WPF How to prevent interaction with controls in background when Popup is open

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

When I display a Popup all other controls in the background appears to be not active (i.e. when I hover over a button for example it does not change a style). When I click somewhere to dismiss the Popup and it just happens to be a button where I clicked, that button takes a hit. This is very confusing, because one would assume that they can click anywhere to dismiss the popup and not just the empty space.

How to prevent interaction with controls in background when Popup is open?

OR

How to make controls in background react to the mouse hover even when Popup is open (like ToolTip)?

Setting `IsHitTestVisible` either to true or false seems to have no effect.

Comment: Put a low opacity rectangle or something on top of everything. Make it collapse unless the popup is visible. Then all they can click is the rectangle..

Comment: Thanks @Andy. This is what I'm doing now. I was wondering if there is a better approach.